# Proving uncountability of a set

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

Let $A$ be a subset of the real numbers, containing every integer, and such that for every $x$ and $y$ in A, there exists $z$ in A strictly comprised between them. Prove $A$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick $A=\mathbb Q$. Then $A$ has the given property but $A$ is countable.

Comment: Ok, I feel a little dumb now. Thanks